# Pyspark date format from multiple columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have four string columns `'hour', 'day', 'month', 'year'` in my data frame. I would like to create new column fulldate in format `'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'`.

```
df2 = df1.withColumn("fulldate", to_date(concat(col('day'), lit('/'), col('month'), lit('/'), col('year'), lit(' '), col('hour'), lit(':'), lit('0'), lit('0')), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'))
```

but it doesn't seem to work. I'm getting format "yyyy-mm-dd".

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

For Spark 3+, you can use [`make_timestamp`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#make_timestamp) function to create a timestamp column from those columns and use [`date_format`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#date_format) to convert it to the desired date pattern :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df2 = df1.withColumn(
    "fulldate",
    F.date_format(
        F.expr("make_timestamp(year, month, day, hour, 0, 0)"),
        "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `date_format` instead of `to_date`.

`to_date` converts a column to date type **from** the given format, while `date_format` converts a date type column **to** the given format.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import date_format, concat, col, lit

df2 = df1.withColumn(
    "fulldate",
    date_format(
        concat(col('year'), lit('/'), col('month'), lit('/'), col('day'), lit(' '), col('hour'), lit(':'), lit('00'), lit(':'), lit('00')),
        'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'
    )
)
```

For better readability, you can use `format_string`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import date_format, format_string, col

df2 = df1.withColumn(
    "fulldate",
    date_format(
        format_string('%d/%d/%d %d:00:00', col('year'), col('month'), col('day'), col('hour')),
        'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'
    )
)
```

Comment: `date_format` takes a date/timestamp type and returns a string in the given format pattern. `to_date` returns a date type from a date string using the given pattern. You need to add `to_timestamp(conact(...` and `to_timestamp(format_string(...` otherwise it will return null I think.

Comment: @blackbishop Correct me if I'm wrong, but the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.date_format) says that `date_format` takes string type too...?

Comment: Yes, but only when the string date is in the default format: `yyyy-MM-dd` for dates or `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` for timestamps.

Comment: @blackbishop Ah, thanks, I didn't realize it wasn't in standard format. Will edit to make sure that's standard